# Struts2 multiple forms with token not working. Only one token at a time working

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to develop an application in struts2 where I have multiple forms and may or may not have same action. To avoid CSRF I also added token with these forms, but only one token at a time working. If I clicked on another submit button then I am redirecting to error page which is configured for CSRF. I am stuck here why this is happening, am not able to use multiple token on same page or is there any solution for this.

Please find struts2.xml code which I have configured.

```
<action name="expUsers" class="com.org.action.ExpUser">
   <interceptor-ref name="CSRFStack"/>
   <result name="invalid.token" type="tiles">csrfError</result>
   <result name="success" type="stream">
       <param name="contentDisposition">contentDisposition</param>
       <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
       <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
   </result>
   <result name="failed" type="chain">csrfError</result>             
</action>
```

I have the following dummy form example below which will let you understand what i am doing.

```
<form id="form-1">
<s:token/>
....
</form>

<form id="form-2">
<s:token/>
....
</form>

<form id="form-3">
<s:token/>
....
</form>

... so on multiple forms with token.
```

Comment: @Monoj i think since token are unique(for every request)...only one submission or request will be taken for that token! And thats what multiple request for one token are not allowed :) :)

Comment: You shouldn't use the same token for both forms.

Comment: Then how to generate different token for each forms, as whatever forms i have, i what to generate new token for each form. I will have multiple forms based on DB records.

Comment: If user go back and click on another form then form should work after using token on first request.

Comment: Go back via browser back button? Does the first form should work also? Don't forget to mention people so they can get notification @ManojSharma .

Comment: You would need to get a new token using ajax and set the value to respective form before submission.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Do you want the solution which handles back button problems? If not then using token tag w/o name on multiple forms is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to All for giving me your suggestion. I have found a working solution so i am giving answer to my own question.

When we generate `<s:token/>` then the hidden field will be generate like this:-

```
<input type="hidden" name="struts.token.name" value="token">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="1IPDKJ3QWM8X4JXAV0RKC0A9XVQ4I83E">
```

which is default behavior. Now if i want to generate different token for each struts2 token tag then i have to specify the unique name to token like this :-

```
<s:token name="unique-1"/>
```

Then it will generate hidden field like this:-

```
<input type="hidden" name="struts.token.name" value="unique-1">
<input type="hidden" name="unique-1" value="1IPDKJ3QWM8X4JXAV0RKC0A9XVQ4I83E">
```

Now i have two different token for two different forms in same page and this tricks also working perfectly without any issue at the time of writing this answer.